# Non-file package-anchored link(s) in documentation object

Tags: r, package, documentation

In my R package checking, I got some warnings about documentation links.

```
* checking Rd cross-references ... WARNING
Non-file package-anchored link(s) in documentation object 'show_sig_consensusmap.Rd':
  ‘[NMF:consensusmap]{NMF::consensusmap}’

Non-file package-anchored link(s) in documentation object 'show_sig_number_survey2.Rd':
  ‘[NMF]{summary}’
```

It is strange that such warnings only happen in debian OS.

```
package sigminer_1.0.7.tar.gz does not pass the incoming checks automatically, please see the following pre-tests:
Windows: <https://win-builder.r-project.org/incoming_pretest/sigminer_1.0.7_20200616_163758/Windows/00check.log>
Status: OK
Debian: <https://win-builder.r-project.org/incoming_pretest/sigminer_1.0.7_20200616_163758/Debian/00check.log>
Status: 1 WARNING
```

I can only remove this warning by deleting the links. But after deletion, my users will not be able to get more info by clicking the link.

[image]

Is there a better solution?

Comment: FWIW it looks like this is a reasonably recent change to the package-checking machinery: https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/f27cbf1a52a31cd9b9676340394946a22041a4ae

Comment: would be interested in speculation about why this is only throwing a warning on Debian ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that, if you use links of the form `\code{\link[pkg]{foo}}` pointing to help pages containing several functions, the link should point only to the core function.

For example, say the functions `foo_1` and `foo_2` are described in the same help page and `foo_1` is the main function (i.e. appearing in the top left corner of the help page).

To create a link to `foo_2`, you should use `\code{\link[pkg:foo_1]{foo_2}}`.

See [this GH issue](https://github.com/r-lib/roxygen2/issues/707) and [this reference](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Cross_002dreferences) in writing R extensions.

Comment: A good example of this would be if you want to link to `broom::augment()` in your help file. Since broom's `augment()`, `tidy()`, and `glance()` all point to the same `broom::reexports`, your help file code should look like `\code{\link[broom:reexports]{glance}}`

Comment: How should I document this with markdown supported by roxygen2 package?